# Um produto em Varias Categorias - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, relacionamento

Gostaria de saber como faço para relacionar um produto em varias categorias ? Por Exemplo: Uma camisa pode estar nas Categorias : "Verde / Azul / Amarelo" e quando eu filtrasse pela categoria o produto deve aparecer na categoria "Verde , azul ou Amarelo".

Sei que devo usar o Relacionamento N : N, mas como aplicar isso no codigo em PHP?
Existe outra forma de fazer sem usar o relacionamento N:N, por exemplo por array ?

Comment: Eu usaria isso como cor e não categoria, mas tudo bem. Não fucou muito claro o "varias categorias" da sua pergunta. No caso um produto pode estar em mais de uma, ex.: verde e azul?

Comment: O problema não é de PHP, mas sim de banco de dados. O @Zuul deu uma resposta ótima ilustrando many-to-many no banco que você usa, MySQL. Outros bancos como o PostGre aceitam arrays, e mesmo com o MySQL você tem a opção de salvar as IDs das cores em um único campo, mas no caso do MySQL isso prejudicaria e muito as queries futuras. Sobre o PHP em si, você pode usar arrays ou o que quiser . Eu sugeriria `@camisa['cores'] = [QUERY PARA PEGAR AS CORES COM INNER JOIN];`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Não indicas a estrutura das tuas tabelas, mas para esse efeito deverás fazer uso de uma tabela intermédia que efetivamente servirá o propósito de relacionar cada produto para as múltiplas categorias:

## Diagrama EER

[image: ERR Diagram]

Desta forma, tens uma tabela para os produtos, uma tabela para as categorias e uma tabela para estabelecer a relação entre ambos.

## Exemplo prático

Para o teu caso, o produto "camisa" está com 3 categorias, a "Verde", "Azul" e "Amarelo", pelo que na tabela `produtos_categorias` ele teria três registos:

**Tabela: Produtos**

[image: Tabela Produtos]

**Tabela: Categorias**

[image: Tabela Categorias]

**Tabela de relação: Produtos ~ Categorias**

[image: Tabela de relação entre produtos e categorias]

Desta forma, ao escolherem a categoria `azul` irias realizar uma consulta do tipo:

```sql
SELECT 
    produtos.nome
FROM produtos_categorias
INNER JOIN produtos ON (produtos.id = produtos_categorias.produtos_id)
INNER JOIN categorias ON (
    categorias.id = produtos_categorias.categorias_id
    AND categorias.nome='azul'
)
```

Que te devolve os produtos que estão na categoria `azul`.

---

<sup>A resposta é um exemplo prático de forma abstrata, não reflete performance nem um funcionamento correto para a aplicação a desenvolver. Ilustra-se apenas o procedimento a adotar para lidar com o problema em mãos.</sup>